# Iterate through a FHIR element binding

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to iterate through a FHIR capability statement to pull down a list of all the questions and values sets that are supported by the server.

I have a downloaded FHIR capability statement, and subsequent structure definition and within the structure definition I am iterating through each snapshot element.

Some of the elements have a `binding`, which I can see is correctly populated from the console and debug break points but I can't determine the correct way to access this in code.

For example, the immediate window is giving me the following information about the `element.Binding.ValueSet`:

> **element.Binding.ValueSet**
> {url: [http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category}](http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category%7D)
> Children: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference.<get_Children>d__32}
> Display: null
> DisplayElement: null
> ElementId: null
> Extension: Count = 0
> Identifier: null
> IsContainedReference: false
> NamedChildren: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference.<get_NamedChildren>d__34}
> Reference: "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category"
> ReferenceElement: {Value="http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category"}
> Type: null
> TypeElement: null
> TypeName: "Reference"
> Url: {http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category}
> Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

But I can't access these "Properties", for example:
`element.Binding.ValueSet.Reference` returns

> **element.Binding.ValueSet.Reference**
> error CS1061: 'DataType' does not contain a definition for 'Reference' and no accessible extension method 'Reference' accepting a first argument of type 'DataType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I interrogate the type or properties I get the following:

> **element.Binding.ValueSet.GetType()** (results abridged)
> {Name = "ResourceReference" FullName = "Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference"}
> Assembly: {Hl7.Fhir.Support.Poco, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d706911480550fc3}
> AssemblyQualifiedName: "Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference, Hl7.Fhir.Support.Poco, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=d706911480550fc3"
> BaseType: {Name = "DataType" FullName = "Hl7.Fhir.Model.DataType"}
> DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__22}
> DeclaredProperties: {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[13]}
> FullName: "Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference"
> Module (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {Hl7.Fhir.Support.Poco.dll}
> Module: {Hl7.Fhir.Support.Poco.dll}
> Name: "ResourceReference"
> Namespace: "Hl7.Fhir.Model"
> UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "ResourceReference" FullName = "Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference"}

> **element.Binding.ValueSet.GetType().GetProperties()**
> {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[14]}
> [0]: {System.String TypeName}
> [1]: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.FhirString ReferenceElement}
> [2]: {System.String Reference}
> [3]: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.FhirUri TypeElement}
> [4]: {System.String Type}
> [5]: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.Identifier Identifier}
> [6]: {Hl7.Fhir.Model.FhirString DisplayElement}
> [7]: {System.String Display}
> [8]: {System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Hl7.Fhir.Model.Base] Children}
> [9]: {System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Hl7.Fhir.Model.ElementValue]
> NamedChildren}
> [10]: {System.Uri Url}
> [11]: {Boolean IsContainedReference}
> [12]: {System.String ElementId}
> [13]: {System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Hl7.Fhir.Model.Extension] Extension}

I can convert this object to a list, it appears to be some enumerable of KVPs:

> **element.Binding.ValueSet.ToList()**
> Count = 1
> [0]: {[reference, {Value=http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/adverse-event-category}]}

But calling for the `element.Binding.ValueSet.Keys` or `element.Binding.ValueSet.Values` does not work either

What is the correct way to work with this object?

Comment: Which reference implementation are you using?

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie STU3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using FHIR STU3, `element.Binding.ValueSet` will be of the generic DataType which can mean any of the FHIR datatypes, since this element is a choice property and could be either of type Reference or Uri.
The way to access the data inside is to cast the ValueSet property to ResourceReference or use `as ResourceReference`, after which you'll be able to access the reference properties.